# Hash table init_hash in c

Tags: c, dynamic, hashtable, dynamic-allocation

I need to initialized the hash table with the size i get, i have a problem here `t->arr_table[i]->key = NULL;`

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct element{
    char * key;      
    char * value;    
}element;

typedef struct HashTable{
    int size;    // size of the arr
    element **arr_table;   //arr of elements
}HashTable;


void init_hash(int size, HashTable * t)
{
    if (size < 1)
        return;
    t->size = size;
    t->arr_table = (element **)malloc(sizeof(element*)*size);
    if (t->arr_table == NULL) // out memory
        return;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    { // initial list
        t->arr_table[i]->key = NULL;
        t->arr_table[i]->value = NULL;
    }

}



void main()
{
    HashTable *ht = (HashTable*)malloc(1*sizeof(HashTable));
    int size_ht = 9;
    init_hash(size_ht, ht);
    printf("...\n");
    return;
}
```

Comment: "I have a problem". Don't you think it would make sense to tell us what the problem is exactly? Isn't that common sense?

Comment: Because i don't know why it is happaned @kaylum

Comment: Are you trying to create an ***array of pointers to elements*** or an ***array of elements*** inside the `HashTable` structure?

Comment: Why *what* happened?? You haven't actually told us what bad behaviour you have observed. You must have observed something that is causing you problems. What is that *something*?

Comment: I try to create a array of elements inside HashTable @user3386109

Answer (score 1):

What you've made is an ***array of pointers to elements***. However, the `init_hash` function seems to expect an ***array of elements***. To create an array of elements the code should be as shown below. I've added some comments to highlight some of the changes.

```
typedef struct element{
    char *key;
    char *value;
}element;

typedef struct HashTable{
    int size;
    element *arr_table;     // <-- only one '*', not two, to declare a pointer to an array of elements
}HashTable;

void init_hash(int size, HashTable *t)
{
    if (size < 1)
        return;
    t->size = size;
    t->arr_table = malloc(sizeof(element) * size);  // <-- allocate memory for the elements, note 'sizeof(element)' not 'sizeof(element *)'
    if (t->arr_table == NULL)
        return;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        t->arr_table[i].key = NULL;         // <-- table[i] is a structure, use dot notation
        t->arr_table[i].value = NULL;
    }
}

int main( void )    // <-- declare main with the correct signature
{
    HashTable *ht = malloc(sizeof(HashTable));  // <-- don't cast the return value from malloc
    int size_ht = 9;
    init_hash(size_ht, ht);
    printf("...\n");
}
```